# How a static synchronized function works?

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

When a Java member needs to be thread-safe, we do like the following:

```
 public synchronized void func() {
     ...
 }
```

This syntax equivalent to:

```
 public void func() {
      synchronized(this) {
           ....
      }
 }
```

That is, it actually uses `this` for a lock.

My question is, if I use `synchronized` with a `static` method, as follows:

```
class AA {
    private AA() {}

    public static synchronized AA getInstance() {
        static AA obj = new AA();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

In this case, on what is the lock made for the `synchronized` method?

Comment: The class AA will be locked `synchronized(AA.class)` , but no instances

Comment: Isn't the static declaration of the local variable `obj` a syntax error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case of static synchronized method, the `class` object of your `class AA` will be implicit lock

its equivalent to

```
class AA {
    private AA() {}

    public static AA getInstance() {
        synchronized(AA.class) {
           AA obj = new AA();
           return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. equivalent to `synchronized (AA.class) { `

Comment: but what about `static AA obj = new AA();` - wouldn't it give compile time error ?

Comment: thanks @Bingo i have corrected it now.. I had not paid attention to that code

Comment: @sanbhat well it happens, but u surely deserve upvote +1

Comment: @sanbhat So when we synchronze on `this`, another object cannot execute the synchronized thread, but when synchronized on class? What happens exactly? True that it acquired the lock of the class; does that mean another class cannot execute the synchronized piece of code?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar since the lock object is the `Class` object associated with the class, and there will be only **one** `Class` object, only one thread can execute `static synchronized` methods of a class **at any instance of time**. To make multiple methods of a same class, execute in a mutually exclusive manner, all the method can be declared as `static synchronized`

Comment: @sanbhat, got it :) thanks but what is the use of it? I mean is there any practical use for it? sorry if its a dumb question. But I would like to know

Comment: An old blog written by me i hope should help.. http://bhat86.blogspot.in/2011/06/mutual-exclusion-among-2-different.html

Answer (score 7):

From [section 8.4.3.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used.

So your code acquires the monitor for `AA.class`. As sanbhat says, it's like

```
synchronized(AA.class) {
    ...
}
```

... just as with an instance method it would be

```
synchronized(this) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked on AA.class lock.

```
public static AA getInstance() {
        synchronized(AA.class){
            static AA obj = new AA();
            return obj;
        }

}
```